# Not getting spaces from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input box with submit button and another input box created from script for getting previous input value.When i type "test data" in first input box and press click button, I am getting only "test" in another text box.I need to get same "test data" in script created input box.

**HTML**

```
<input name=""  type="text" id="test" /></td>

<input type="button" onclick="add_values()" id="add_new_code" >click</td>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function add_values()
{
getTest=document.getElementById('test').value;
$('<tr><td><input type=text name=test2[] value='+getTest+'></td></tr>');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add double qoutes

```
$('<tr><td><input type=text name=test2[] value="'+getTest+'"></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add quotes to your generated HTML ... try the following:

```
$('<tr><td><input type="text" value="'+getTest+'"></td></tr>');
```

I'm note at all sure where your "test2[]" comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function add_values()
{
   getTest=document.getElementById('test').value;
   $('<tr><td><input type=text name=test2[] value="'+getTest+'"></td></tr>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, since you have jQuery at hand:

```
function add_values(){
    getTest = $("#test").val();
    $('<tr><td><input type="text" name="test2" value="'+getTest+'"></td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: It was an addon. I forgot to mention the obvious part. i.e the double quotes.